# Complex MYSQL Query 4 tables looking for 1 result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have officially gotten a headache, sorry just had to say that. I have a complex MYSQL Query that I cannot figure out. First let me explain... We have 4 tables seeking 1 answer.

The values needed for each table are as follows

Table 1 -> Sectors

- id

Table 2 -> Categories

- id
- sector_id (only parent categories have this)
- parent_id

Table 3 -> Programs

- id
- title

Table 4 -> Category_Programs

- category_id (these are sub categories)
- program_id

---

Some how I have to select all of the categories where the sector_id = the currently viewed sector.

Then find all of the categories with a parent_id = the primary categories we just found.

After that I need to find all of the program_ids from category_programs where category_id = one of the sub categories we just returned.

The values I need are from programs which are id and title.

I have never done a complex mysql query like this and I am completely lost. My current way of doing this is very inefficient. Please help me.

Comment: So, a 'sector' is simply an orphan 'category'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick is to use `Categories` twice, once in a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM Categories c1
LEFT JOIN Categories c2
  ON c2.parent_id = c1.id
JOIN Category_Programs cp
  ON cp.category_id = c1.id OR cp.category_id = c2.id
JOIN Programs p
  ON p.id = cp.program_id
WHERE c1.sector_id = 1
```

I think you could get duplicates from the `OR` if you have more than one sub category for a particular parent so you may want to add `DISTINCT`.

Alternatively, you could break it down into two queries which would negate the need for the `OR` and the `DISTINCT`, and may actually improve performance:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM Categories c1
JOIN Category_Programs cp
  ON cp.category_id = c1.id
JOIN Programs p
  ON p.id = cp.program_id
WHERE c1.sector_id = 1
UNION
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM Categories c1
JOIN Categories c2
  ON c2.parent_id = c1.id
JOIN Category_Programs cp
  ON cp.category_id = c2.id
JOIN Programs p
  ON p.id = cp.program_id
WHERE c1.sector_id = 1
```

Comment: <3 that was it! I have been killing my self over this. Also can you please explain the use of DISTINCT to me? How exactly would I go about doing this?

Comment: @PatrickMencias-lewis. I updated my answer. Also, `DISTINCT` would go right after `SELECT`, like `SELECT DISTINCT ...`.

Comment: You were right about the duplicates and distinct did remove them as you said. Is there some sort of reading material/video you would recommend on looking into to learn more about MYSQL Querys similar to this?

Comment: `JOIN`, and optionally `UNION`, are simple tools. It was just a more difficult problem. I say, just practice, practice, practice.